# XSLT 1.0 : Iterate over characters in a string

Tags: xslt, xpath

I need to iterate over the characters in a string to build an XML structure.

Currently, I am doing this :

```
<xsl:template name="verticalize">
    <xsl:param name="text">Some text</xsl:param>
    <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(replace(replace($text,'(.)','$1\\n'),'\\n$',''),'\\n')">
        <xsl:element name="para">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This produces something like :

```
<para>S</para>
<para>o</para>
<para>m</para>
<para>e</para>
<para> </para>
<para>t</para>
<para>e</para>
<para>x</para>
<para>t</para>
```

This works fine with Xpath 2.0. But I need to apply the same treatment in a XPath 1.0 environment, where the `replace()` method is not available.

Do you know a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Excellent Question (+1). See my answer for an XSLT 2.0 solution, which also happens to be the shortest so far. :)

Comment: See also my XSLT 1.0 solution. :)

Comment: @Dimitre, if it wasn't the shortest, there would be no point in using XSLT 2.0 ;-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
<xsl:template name="letters">
  <xsl:param name="text" select="'Some text'" />
  <xsl:if test="$text != ''">
    <xsl:variable name="letter" select="substring($text, 1, 1)" />
    <para><xsl:value-of select="$letter" /></para>
    <xsl:call-template name="letters">
      <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $letter)" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Tomalak, you're my XSLT-hero.

Comment: tail recursion is nice until you get a giant XML file that likes to give you stackoverflow errors.

Comment: @DougT. A decent XSLT processor should transform tail recursion into interation, which eliminates the danger of stack overflows. If you have implemented a *tail* recursive solution (as opposed to just recursive) but switching to a different processor is no option for you, you might try changing the approach to divide and conquer.

Answer (score 9):

If the string length is not huge, you can use a recursively called template to achieve this, passing the index of the character to be processed as parameter into the template.

Like so:

```
<xsl:template name="verticalize">
    <xsl:param name="text">Some text</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="index" select="1" />
    <xsl:if test="string-length($text) &gt;= $index">
        <xsl:element name="para">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($text, $index, 1)"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:call-template name="verticalize">
            <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text" />
            <xsl:with-param name="index" select="$index+1" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

If the string is longer than that, you can use a similar approach but with a divide-and-conquer algorithm, so that you have a maximum recursion depth of log2(string-length), like so:

```
<xsl:template name="verticalize">
    <xsl:param name="text">Some text</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="left" select="1" />
    <xsl:param name="right" select="string-length($text)" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$left = $right">
            <xsl:element name="para">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($text, $left, 1)"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$left &lt; $right">
            <xsl:variable name="middle" select="floor(($left+$right) div 2)" />
            <xsl:call-template name="verticalize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text" />
                <xsl:with-param name="left" select="$left" />
                <xsl:with-param name="right" select="$middle" />
            </xsl:call-template>
            <xsl:call-template name="verticalize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="$text" />
                <xsl:with-param name="left" select="$middle+1" />
                <xsl:with-param name="right" select="$right" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You're welcome - but why did you not award me the answer points? I was 3 minutes before Tomalak and has already posted the first sample...

Comment: @Lucero: You posted a boilerplate answer without code. I had my code ready before you did. ;) But you get +1 from me for the divide/conquer variant. One hint though: Recursing over the rest of the string only (`substring-after()`) minimizes memory usage. Your recursion passes a copy of the entire string in every step, and this adds up until the stack unwinds.

Comment: @Tomalak, I think you're wrong about the memory usage. Typically, my code with the `select` of a unchanged text node will always pass on a reference to the same text node instead of re-creating a string copy on each call, thereby it should be much cheaper in that is uses *less* memory and avoids copying the string over and over again. (And regarding the point in time, it is in the 1st revision, maybe I added it in the 5-minute window, can't remember.)

Comment: @Lucero: Granted, if you work with actual text nodes then I'd expect it would pass a reference and a bunch of integers around. Different processors would implement this differently internally, so I guess testing/benchmarking would be required.

Comment: @Lucero : it was a close tie but Tomalak's answer seemed more elegant. I knew you'd complain though, they all do... :)

Answer (score 8):

## **An XSLT 2.0 Solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vText" select="'Some Text'"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="string-to-codepoints($vText)">
      <para><xsl:sequence select="codepoints-to-string(.)"/></para>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**For those of you, learning XSLT 2.0 /XPath 2.0, do note**:

1. The use of the standard XPath 2.0 functions [**`string-to-codepoints()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-to-codepoints) and [**`codepoints-to-string()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-codepoints-to-string).
2. In XSLT 2.0 the value of the `select` attribute of `<xsl:for-each>` may be a sequence of any items, not only nodes.

Comment: Nice solution. However, it will not work as expected when combining characters are used to represent accents etc.: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character

Comment: @Lucero: That's interesting. Could you give me a "combined character" example, so that I would better understand? Also, it seems to me that none of the other solutions would work in this case either.

Comment: @Dimitre, for samples have a look at Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_normalization

I'm not sure whether the other solutions would work or not; I'd expect the string functions to work on composed characters, since everything else would break the single (textual) characters. I'd have to check in the XPath/XSLT specs on how these work.

Comment: @Dimitre, have a look at the `normalize-unicode` XSLT 2 function: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-normalize-unicode - I guess that might help with getting a correct result.

Comment: @D̀i̫m̴i̐t̽r̾e̚, I'm not sure whether this works across the browser and SO storage, so it may be best to generate one yourself: on a Windows machine, open the character map (charmap.exe), choose "Arial" as font and "Unicode" as character set, choose to group by "Unicode Subrange", take "Combining Diactrical Marks", type a character (abc... whatever you like!), and then append any one, two or even more combining marks just as you like (more than 2 may not be displayed). You'll see that those get applied to the character you have typed, and hitting backspace will remove them one by one as well.

Comment: (cont.) Another amazing feature of Unicode is the Complex Text Layout, which allows combining complex characters similar to the diacritic system: द + ् + ध + ् + र + ् + य = द्ध्र्य - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_text_layout - these should ideally be handled as one character as well I think...

Answer (score 2):

## **An XSLT 1.0 Solution using FXSL**

The [**FXSL library**](http://fxsl.sf.net) offers a number of generic functions for list processing. Almost all of them have an analog for operating on strings (regarding a string as a list of characters).

Here is an example using the `str-foldl` function/template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:dvc-foldl-func="dvc-foldl-func"
exclude-result-prefixes="xsl dvc-foldl-func"
>

   <xsl:import href="dvc-str-foldl.xsl"/>

   <dvc-foldl-func:dvc-foldl-func/>
   <xsl:variable name="vFoldlFun" select="document('')/*/dvc-foldl-func:*[1]"/>
    <xsl:output  encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

      <xsl:call-template name="dvc-str-foldl">
        <xsl:with-param name="pFunc" select="$vFoldlFun"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="123456789"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pA0" select="0"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dvc-foldl-func:*">
         <xsl:param name="arg1" select="0"/>
         <xsl:param name="arg2" select="0"/>

         <xsl:value-of select="$arg1 + $arg2"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**This transformation calculates the sum of the characters in the string** passed as the `$pStr` parameter and produces the correct result:

45

**And using the `str-map` template/function we have the following easy and short solution:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:testmap="testmap"
exclude-result-prefixes="xsl testmap"
>
   <xsl:import href="str-dvc-map.xsl"/>

   <!-- to be applied on any xml source -->

   <testmap:testmap/>

   <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:variable name="vTestMap" select="document('')/*/testmap:*[1]"/>
     <xsl:call-template name="str-map">
       <xsl:with-param name="pFun" select="$vTestMap"/>
       <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="'Some Text'"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="split" match="*[namespace-uri() = 'testmap']">
      <xsl:param name="arg1"/>

      <para><xsl:value-of select="$arg1"/></para>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on any XML file (not used), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<para>S</para>
<para>o</para>
<para>m</para>
<para>e</para>
<para> </para>
<para>T</para>
<para>e</para>
<para>x</para>
<para>t</para>
```