# XSLT iteration or recursion performance

Tags: performance, xslt, recursion, iteration

Has anyone measured the performance of running <strike>equivalent</strike> *similar* XSL transformations iteratively or recursively using various libraries? I'm most curious about Java libraries, but other suggestions are welcome too.

Example for iteration (valid, <strike>given</strike> *assuming* that `//*` probably matches quite a few elements for the example, but not "true" to the "spirit" of XSLT):

```
<xsl:for-each select="//*[position() &lt;= string-length(MyData/MyValue)]">
  <someTags>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring(MyData/MyValue, position(), 1)"/>
  </someTags>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Example for recursion (pure, but quite verbose for the same task):

```
<xsl:template match="data/node">
  <xsl:call-template name="for-each-character">                    
    <xsl:with-param name="data" select="."/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="for-each-character">                
  <xsl:param name="data"/>
  <xsl:if test="string-length($data) &gt; 0">
    <someTags>                            
      <xsl:value-of select="substring($data,1,1)"/>
    </someTags>
    <xsl:call-template name="for-each-character">
      <xsl:with-param name="data" select="substring($data,2)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Both examples were taken from this question:

[XSLT for each letter in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680437/xslt-for-each-letter-in-a-string)

**Note**: Stack Overflow tends to be a place for heated discussions about the purity of XSLT and beginners having to learn XSLT correctly. While I don't care much about the verboseness of "purity", or the rather subjective "purity" itself, I really wonder about performance here.

Comment: I asked a similar question a while ago, named templates are slightly worse on performance in general, will see if i can find where i read it.

Comment: But what about the recursion itself? The implementation will need to maintain large stacks. Depending on the number of variables in the context of every stack level, this could mean quite a lot...

Comment: You'll probably call me a purist for saying this, but performance almost has to be a secondary consideration to correctness. The iteration example above obviously has the very real possibility of ending prematurely. Getting the wrong result faster should never be considered better than a slower correct result.

Comment: I don't think you can state that the to solutions above are _equivalent_. Intuitively, the first solution is _really_ heavy in terms of performances, because you ask the processor to traverse the entire input tree for each letter. While in the second case, yes, it's recursion, but you are not going to have problems because you  are treating _words_, so even this `supercalifragilistichespiralitoso` will result fine.

Comment: can't seem to find the information, i was looking at performance issues a while ago whilst working on some very large datasets

Comment: @empo, I'm guessing it depends on the processor, but in any functional language it should be safe to assume that that list isn't going to change on each iteration, so realistically the processor should only need to traverse it once. I still think it's a bad solution though, not because it's 'anti-purist', but because it's not reliable.

Comment: Performance question are best answered by running sample code against sample data and measuring the performance. The named template seems tail-recursive so with the right optimization in the XSLT processor you might at least not get a stackoverflow for long strings. Whilst the for-each could run out of elements for long strings. But you know that, if performance is the question then measure it. I would do it with XSLT 2.0 any way: `<xsl:for-each select="string-to-codepoints(MyData/MyValue)"><someTags><xsl:value-of select="codepoints-to-string(.)"/></someTags></xsl:for-each>`.

Comment: @Flynn, you are probably true. It's bad anyway to traverse the entire tree, without a meaningful reason.

Comment: Guys guys guys. Don't start the "reliable" discussion. Lets **ASSESS** for the above problem, that `//*` matches all the elements in the universe, i.e. `10^80`. If you don't like that, I'll create a better iteration looping over a well-defined set of elements...

Comment: @empo: I want to *know* not guess. I think XSL is functional, so the condition is evaluated before the actual matching. With a smart implementation, I might actually match only what I need. With a bad implementation, of course, I'll wind up with a horrible loop. But I want to know if someone has already *measured* these things...

Comment: Well, my point was if you're going to compare iteration/recursion, you need to use a 'good' example of iteration. An XSLT 2.0 example that iterates through an analysed string compared with a recursive template that uses `substring-after` would be a better comparison.

Comment: @Flynn: You are right. I didn't express clearly enough, that the concrete examples are not important for my question...

Comment: Yeah, it is difficult to come up with a good example though, there's very few cases where it's not pretty obvious which is the better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might answer your question  Lukas

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506348/how-do-i-know-my-xsl-is-efficient-and-beautiful

Comment: Awesome, that seems to be a very nice list of good answers and different view-points! Thanks!

Comment: dimitre novatchev has a blog (http://dnovatchev.wordpress.com/) with some real interesting stuff  on Im sure there is info on that also :)

Comment: Yeah, nice to know. He's the master of purists, from what I've seen on Stack Overflow. Maybe I'm going to be converted :D

Comment: @Lucas Eder: I don't know what do you mean by "master of purists". My recommendation is always when possible to avoid recursion (unless you really know what you are doing). I have a long history of implementing non-recursive solutions that are significantly more efficient -- see this 8-year old article: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/08/06/exslt.html

Comment: @Dimitre: Thanks for the link! I didn't mean to insult you. I respect your work. It's just a silly remark because I tend to get downvoted on SO for my XSLT hacks. Once by you, I think :)

Comment: @Lucas Eder: Give me a link to your answer and I will cancel the downvote :)