# How to read text from xsl and each text should place in each tag

Tags: xslt-1.0

The source file contains

```
<p>TEST</p>
```

The output desired applying the XSLT to the input file:

```
<p>T</p>
<p>E</p>
<p>S</p>
<p>T</p>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: The short answer is **yes**. A longer answer you will find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680437/xslt-for-each-letter-in-a-string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can try recursion in XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
    <xsl:call-template name="for-each-character">
      <xsl:with-param name="data" select="p/text()"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="for-each-character">
    <xsl:param name="data"/>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($data) &gt; 0">
      <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring($data,1,1)"/>
      </p>
      <xsl:call-template name="for-each-character">
        <xsl:with-param name="data" select="substring($data,2,string-length($data))"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Hope this helps.